# SQL Server : how can I merge these 2 queries together using a distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query that gets a list of distinct deviceID's, now I want to join that query with another query that has an inner join.

This is my first query

```
Select distinct deviceid 
from session 
where cast(createdon as date) between '01/01/2018' and '01/30/2018' 
  and len(deviceid) > 10
```

That query returns the distinct DeviceId's I need. I now want to use that DeviceID from that query and replace it with the DeviceID in this query

Second query:

```
select f.PracticeID, F.Name, D.DeviceID, d.SerialNumber 
from device d
inner join facility f on f.id = d.locationid
inner join session s on s.deviceid = d.deviceid 
where d.deviceID = 'deviceID'
```

How can I merge those 2? I want to get the results from 1st query and use it for the 2nd query DeviceID column. Right now I am manually executing the `DeviceID` in the second query that I get from the first. I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Be careful with those dates. You should use the ANSI dateformat YYYYMMDD. With those strings the way you have them they can be misinterpreted based on the local dateformat which can be changed for the current connection and the default changes based on the language of the install.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get all the data from the second query for the distinct DeviceID from the first one?  This should do it.

```
select f.PracticeID,F.Name,D.DeviceID,d.SerialNumber from device d
inner join facility f on f.id=d.locationid
inner join session s on s.deviceid=d.deviceid 
where d.deviceID in (
     Select distinct deviceid from session where cast(createdon as date) between 
     '01/01/2018' and '01/30/2018' and len(deviceid)>10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query to achieve this :-

```
select f.PracticeID,F.Name,D.DeviceID,d.SerialNumber from ( Select distinct deviceid from session where cast(createdon as date) between 
'01/01/2018' and '01/30/2018' and len(deviceid)>10) d
inner join facility f on f.id=d.locationid
inner join session s on s.deviceid=d.deviceid 
where d.deviceID='deviceID'
```